# gmap3 - Loop through markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops, markers

We want to loop trough all markers that are on the google map. The reason that we want to do this is: We want to change the icon of all the markers.

We have written an if statement that makes an distinction between the markers and the marker we clicked on.

```
if (marker.id==$i) {
  marker.setIcon('assets/images/website/marker-active.png');
} else {
  if (marker.id != 777) {
    marker.setIcon('assets/images/website/marker.png');
  }
}
```

But we are unable to find out how to perform the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to hash the markers upon their creation. There are a number of ways to do this but here's a simple one to get you started:

```
var markers = {};
$.getJSON('marker_data.php').then(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(record) {
        options = foo; //create the options object for the marker
        markers[record.id] = new google.maps.marker(foo);
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could store them in an array, but that could make it harder to retrieve a specific marker, I tend to cache them in an object by id.

Once you have the hash/array, its easy enough to iterate:

```
for (var id in markers) {
    if (id == activeID) {
        marker.setIcon('assets/images/website/marker-active.png');
    } else if (id != 777) {
        marker.setIcon('assets/images/website/marker.png');
    }
}
```

My example assumes you're using jQuery for AJAX and php on the backend, but adjust to suit your stack.